# How do you visualize the electric field exciting this vibration in a molecule?

Tags: electromagnetism, molecules

This image is very common in chemistry, where most people don't really visualize the electric field that produces molecular excitation.

[image]

What would be a good first picture to think about? Maybe it could be classically reduced to a dipole interacting with light, correct?

Is there a not overly complex way to understand how would light make a dipole to vibrate ? (I am not a physicist.)

Answer (score 0):

On the picture the wave is monochromatic end describes by formula
$$E(x,t)=sin(\omega t-kx)$$
So if we put there coordinate of dipole $x_d$ we'll obtain
$$E(t)=sin(\omega t+kx_d)=sin(\omega t + \Delta\varphi)$$
I think the best way to visualize it is to draw vectors of field, that point to the direction where dipole will be orientated:
https://qph.cf2.quoracdn.net/main-qimg-61a9b7da3df652e758498852a14e2101

And also you should draw the dipole orientation from negatively charged side to positively charged one
[image]

Comment: The interaction of a dipole with electromagnetic radiation depends on the frequency. See http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/mod3.html

Comment: yes, but it's hard to visualize it

Comment: The link I gave you has many visuals